# Using nHibernate, how can I read uncommited?

Tags: nhibernate

Using nhibernate, how can I set the transaction level to read uncommitted?

With SQL, I usually set the transaction level at teh beginning of my stored procedure or use inline (NOLOCK).

Comment: Whatever you're doing, read uncommitted is really asking for troubles. I've never seen a real reason to use this. Applications that are actually disabling transaction isolation are not using transactions properly.

Comment: Thats a bit of a dba myth. It’s design choice and like all design choices should be based upon the domain you operate in. For basic small to medium web projects and client apps (which I guess is where the overwhelming majority of folk work) then it’s probably the right thing to do. The decision is cost vs risk, in real-time environments running transaction-less with dirty-reads is pretty much the norm. Huge ecommerce sites (like ebay) will also share many design decisions with RT apps, the transaction levels are so high its just too much risk using them. The cost of rollbacks will cripple you.

Comment: Martin Fowler commented on it here:

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Transactionless.html

Comment: Here is my solution by using SQL Interceptor.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302746/how-do-add-nolock-with-nhibernate/39518098#39518098

Answer (score 3):

[According to the documentation,](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html#d0e875) you can set it via `hibernate.connection.isolation`. If you need more precise control, look into NHibernate's [pessimistic locking](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/transactions.html#transactions-locking) mechanisms.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nolock` in-line SQLs with nhibernate by using following steps:

1. Create HBM File with following

   ```
   <sql-query name="PersonList">
   return alias="person"  class="Person">
   SELECT * FROM Person WITH(nolock) 
   <sql-query>
   ```
2. Use `AddXmlFile(hbm file path)` while creating nhibernate session.
3. Using `DBSession.GetNamedQuery("PersonList")` get the list of persons.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (SQL server specific)

```
  IDbCommand NHCommand;

  NHCommand= NHSession.Connection.CreateCommand();

  NHCommand.CommandText= "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED";

  NHCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Kind of talking to the RDBMS direclty.