# How do add NOLOCK with nHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, criteria

How do you add NOLOCK when using nhibernate? (criteria query)

Answer (score 23):

[`SetLockMode(LockMode.None)`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-optional-dialects) or [`connection.isolation ReadUncomitted`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc) does NOT append a `NOLOCK` to your queries.

Ayende goes into the [correct answer on his blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/17/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-named-queries-ltquerygt-and-ltsql-querygt.aspx):

If you're using `<sql-query>` you can do the following:

```
<sql-query name="PeopleByName">
    <return alias="person"
                    class="Person"/>
    SELECT {person.*}
    FROM People {person} WITH(nolock)
    WHERE {person}.Name LIKE :name
</sql-query>
```

Note the `WTIH(nolock)` appended to the `FROM` clause.

Comment: But setting the connection transaction isolation level to 'read uncommitted' is equivalent to adding (nolock) to every table in a query, right?

Comment: The difference is I suppose that NOLOCK specifies a specific table while read uncommitted specifies every table in the select. I can't imagine that would an issue very often... but maybe.

Comment: @codeulike I will argue with no, Please refer this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx ; As it might help with similar functionality but it is not same and nolock helps you read data which are sometimes called dirty read, but that is what helps you in improving the speed while dealing with millions of rows or records.. else why one will choose nHibernate !!

Comment: Hey, Oracle don't have Read Uncommitted, so how I do this?

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind Oracle works similar to SQL Server's READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT  https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173763.aspx

Answer (score 21):

I'll explain how to do this so that you can add NOLOCK (or any other query hints), whilst still using ICriteria or HQL, and without having to stick knowledge of your queries into the mappings or session factory configuration.

I wrote this for NHibernate 2.1. There are a number of major caveats with it, mostly due to bugs in NHibernate when "use_sql_comments" is turned on (see below). I'm not sure if these bugs have been fixed in NH 3, but try it out. **UPDATE:** Bugs have not been fixed as of NH 3.3. The technique and workarounds I describe here still work.

Firstly, create an interceptor, like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class QueryHintInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    internal const string QUERY_HINT_NOLOCK_COMMENT = "queryhint-nolock: ";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a comment to add to a sql query to tell this interceptor to add 'OPTION (TABLE HINT(table_alias, INDEX = index_name))' to the query.
    /// </summary>
    internal static string GetQueryHintNoLock(string tableName)
    {
        return QUERY_HINT_NOLOCK_COMMENT + tableName;
    }

    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        if (sql.ToString().Contains(QUERY_HINT_NOLOCK_COMMENT))
        {
            sql = ApplyQueryHintNoLock(sql, sql.ToString());
        }

        return base.OnPrepareStatement(sql);
    }

    private static SqlString ApplyQueryHintNoLock(SqlString sql, string sqlString)
    {
        var indexOfTableName = sqlString.IndexOf(QUERY_HINT_NOLOCK_COMMENT) + QUERY_HINT_NOLOCK_COMMENT.Length;

        if (indexOfTableName < 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Query hint comment should contain name of table, like this: '/* queryhint-nolock: tableName */'");

        var indexOfTableNameEnd = sqlString.IndexOf(" ", indexOfTableName + 1);

        if (indexOfTableNameEnd < 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Query hint comment should contain name of table, like this: '/* queryhint-nlock: tableName */'");

        var tableName = sqlString.Substring(indexOfTableName, indexOfTableNameEnd - indexOfTableName).Trim();

        var regex = new Regex(@"{0}\s(\w+)".F(tableName));

        var aliasMatches = regex.Matches(sqlString, indexOfTableNameEnd);

        if (aliasMatches.Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find aliases for table with name: " + tableName);

        var q = 0;
        foreach (Match aliasMatch in aliasMatches)
        {
            var alias = aliasMatch.Groups[1].Value;
            var aliasIndex = aliasMatch.Groups[1].Index + q + alias.Length;

            sql = sql.Insert(aliasIndex, " WITH (NOLOCK)");
            q += " WITH (NOLOCK)".Length;
        }
        return sql;
    }

    private static SqlString InsertOption(SqlString sql, string option)
    {
        // The original code used just "sql.Length". I found that the end of the sql string actually contains new lines and a semi colon.
        // Might need to change in future versions of NHibernate.
        var regex = new Regex(@"[^\;\s]", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
        var insertAt = regex.Match(sql.ToString()).Index + 1;
        return sql.Insert(insertAt, option);
    }
}
```

Then create some nice extension methods somewhere:

```
public static class NHibernateQueryExtensions
{
    public static IQuery QueryHintNoLock(this IQuery query, string tableName)
    {
        return query.SetComment(QueryHintInterceptor.GetQueryHintNoLock(tableName));
    }

    public static ICriteria QueryHintNoLock(this ICriteria query, string tableName)
    {
        return query.SetComment(QueryHintInterceptor.GetQueryHintNoLock(tableName));
    }
}
```

Next, tell NHibernate to use your interceptor:

```
config.SetInterceptor(new QueryHintInterceptor());
```

Finally, enable the *use_sql_comments* property in your NHibernate configuration.

And you're done! Now you can add nolock hints like this:

```
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Foo>()
    .QueryHintNoLock("tableFoo")
    .List<Foo>();
```

I based this work around the technique described here: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/07/23/use-sql-server-query-hints-with-nhibernate-hql-and-icriteria/

**NHibernate Showstopping Bugs:**

Firstly, there is [this bug](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/07/28/a-strange-bug-in-nhibernate-2-1/) with NHibernate that you will need to fix.
(You can either fix this bug by repairing the NHibernate source directly, or [by doing what I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461658/nhibernate-2nd-lvl-cache-custom-query-sqldialect/8470091#8470091) and creating your own Dialect which repairs the issue).

Secondly, there is another bug which seems to occur when you do a paged query, on any page after the first page, and you are using projections. The sql generated by NHibernate is completely wrong around the "OVER" clause. At this stage I don't know how to fix this bug but I'm working on it. **UPDATE:** I have detailed how to fix this bug [here](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/da1c9d2e7ce39999). Like the other bug, this one can also be fixed either by repairing the NHibernate source code or by creating your own Dialect class.

Comment: This procedure build a sql dynamically. What about caching benefits doing this ?

Answer (score 9):

If you are going to use it in a lot of your queries, you can set it as default via the configuration property `connection.isolation`.

```
<property name="connection.isolation">ReadUncommitted</property>
```

Check out the [documentation on this property](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc).

Comment: This worked for me! Changing the web.config entry from ReadCommitted to ReadUncommitted eliminated the DEADLOCK exceptions.  I understand that the reads can now be 'dirty' but I think that's a better alternative than blocking and killing the user's session/experience.  If they view dirty data it's assumed it hasn't updated on the view yet and it will be there next pageview.  Good solution.  Though it doesn't address the actual issue, and the pages still take a long time to load - it has eliminated the DEADLOCK errors.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't add NOLOCK to your queries that I can tell, but it should provide the same functionality - which is to perform dirty reads only inside a transaction.

```
Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
```

I used Sql Profiler to see what the above command would do but it didn't change anything about the query or add NOLOCK to them (nhibernate uses sp_executesql for most my queries).  I ran with it anyway, and it appears all the deadlocks are gone.  Our software has been running this way for 3 days now without deadlocks.  Before this change I could usually reproduce the deadlocks within 15 minutes.  I'm not 100% convinced this fixed it but after another weeks worth of testing I will know more.

This has worked for others as well: http://quomon.com/NHibernate-deadlock-problem-q43633.aspx

Comment: While this solution solves the original problem, it might create another one: now you have an explicit transaction open, so with the default flush behavior you suddenly get extra CPU use and possibly roundtrips to DB somewhere where you have not seem them before. Just need to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by using Interceptor.

```
var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession(new NoLockInterceptor());
```

Here is the implementation for the NoLockInterceptor class.
Basically the NoLockInterceptor class will insert "WITH (NOLOCK)" hint after each table names in the select query, generated by nHibernate.

---

```
public class NoLockInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
        {
            //var log = new StringBuilder();
            //log.Append(sql.ToString());
            //log.AppendLine();

            // Modify the sql to add hints
            if (sql.StartsWithCaseInsensitive("select"))
            {
                var parts = sql.ToString().Split().ToList();
                var fromItem = parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Trim().Equals("from", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                int fromIndex = fromItem != null ? parts.IndexOf(fromItem) : -1;
                var whereItem = parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Trim().Equals("where", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                int whereIndex = whereItem != null ? parts.IndexOf(whereItem) : parts.Count;

                if (fromIndex == -1)
                    return sql;

                parts.Insert(parts.IndexOf(fromItem) + 3, "WITH (NOLOCK)");
                for (int i = fromIndex; i < whereIndex; i++)
                {
                    if (parts[i - 1].Equals(","))
                    {
                        parts.Insert(i + 3, "WITH (NOLOCK)");
                        i += 3;
                    }
                    if (parts[i].Trim().Equals("on", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        parts[i] = "WITH (NOLOCK) on";
                    }
                }
                // MUST use SqlString.Parse() method instead of new SqlString()
                sql = SqlString.Parse(string.Join(" ", parts));
            }

            //log.Append(sql);
            return sql;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public class NoLockInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// OnPrepare.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql">Query.</param>
    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        var begin = SqlString.Parse("with query as (");
        var end = SqlString.Parse(") select * from query with ( nolock )");

        return base.OnPrepareStatement(begin + sql + end);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have taken @cbp answer and changed it a bit:

```
private static SqlString ApplyQueryHintNoLock(SqlString sql)
    {
        var sqlString = sql.ToString();

        if (_cache.Get(sqlString) is SqlString cachedSql)
        {
            //return cachedSql;
        }

        var regex1 = new Regex(@" FROM\s+[a-zA-Z1-9_.]*\s+([a-zA-Z1-9_.]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var regex2 = new Regex(@"(?: INNER JOIN| LEFT OUTER JOIN)\s+[a-zA-Z1-9_.]*\s+([a-zA-Z1-9_.]*) ON", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        var tableAliasMatches = regex1.Matches(sqlString);
        var joinsAliasMatches = regex2.Matches(sqlString);
        var combined = tableAliasMatches.OfType<Match>()
            .Concat(joinsAliasMatches.OfType<Match>())
            .Where(m => m.Success)
            .OrderBy(m=>m.Index);
        var noLockLength = " WITH (NOLOCK)".Length;
        var q = 0;

        foreach (Match aliasMatch in combined)
        {
            var alias = aliasMatch.Groups[1].Value;
            var aliasIndex = aliasMatch.Groups[1].Index + q + alias.Length;

            sql = sql.Insert(aliasIndex, " WITH (NOLOCK)");
            q += noLockLength;
        }

        _cache.Set(sqlString, sql, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(3));

        return sql;
    }

    internal static string GetQueryHintNoLock()
    {
        return _queryHintNoLockCommentString;
    }
```

this way it will add no lock to all tables and inner joins in the query.

this is good for all of you using the unit of work pattern.

Comment: I changed your regex from 1-9 to 0-9 and from then on it appears to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my changes for hibernate which I did at my project

Update hibernate config

```
<prop key="hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector">com____.util.SqlCommentStatementInspector</prop>
```

Implementing StatementInspector

```
public class SqlCommentStatementInspector implements StatementInspector {

    @Override
    public String inspect(String sql) {
        return WithNoLockUtil.handleSqlStatement(sql);
    }

}


public class WithNoLockUtil {

    public static final String WITH_NO_LOCK = " with(nolock) ";
    private static final String OPTION = "OPTION";

    private static boolean withNoLock(String s) {
        if(s == null) return false;
        int len = s.length();
        if(len >= WITH_NO_LOCK.length()){
            String noLockStatement = s.substring(len - 1 - WITH_NO_LOCK.length(), len - 1);
            return noLockStatement.equals(WITH_NO_LOCK);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void deleteOptionStatement(StringBuilder sb) {
        sb.delete(sb.lastIndexOf(OPTION) - 1, sb.length());
    }

    private static void addWithNoLockForFrom(StringBuilder sb) {
        int idx = sb.indexOf(" from ");
        if(idx != -1){
            int count = 4;
            for(int i = idx; i < sb.length(); i++){
                if(sb.charAt(i) == ' ') count--;
                if(count == 0) {
                    sb.insert(i, WITH_NO_LOCK);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addWithNoLockForJoin(StringBuilder sb) {
        int idx = sb.indexOf(" join ");
        if(idx != -1){
            int count = 4;
            for(int i = idx; i < sb.length(); i++){
                if(sb.charAt(i) == ' ') count--;
                if(count == 0) {
                    sb.insert(i, WITH_NO_LOCK);
                    count = 3;
                    i = sb.indexOf(" join ", i);
                    if(i == -1) break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String buildWithNoLockStatement(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        addWithNoLockForFrom(sb);
        addWithNoLockForJoin(sb);
        deleteOptionStatement(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String handleSqlStatement(String sql){
        return withNoLock(sql) ? buildWithNoLockStatement(sql) : sql;
    }
}
```

In query add hint to handle your sql

```
query.addQueryHint(WithNoLockUtil.WITH_NO_LOCK);
```