# NHibernate 2nd lvl cache, custom query, sqldialect

Tags: nhibernate, second-level-cache

I got trunk version of NH and FNH. When i try to add 2nd level cache, some parts of NHibernate forgets about chosen sqldialect.

---

Initial configuration:

```
var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
    .ConnectionString(connectionString)
    .DefaultSchema("dbo")
    .UseReflectionOptimizer()    
  .Mappings(m => ................);
```

Guilty custom query:

```
var sql = @"with Foo(col1,col2,col3)
              as (select bla bla bla...)
            Select bla bla bla from Foo";

list = Session.CreateSQLQuery(sql)
  .AddEntity("fizz", typeof(Fizz))
  .SomethingUnimportant();
```

When i change configuration to:

```
var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
    .ConnectionString(connectionString)
    .DefaultSchema("dbo")
     .UseReflectionOptimizer()
     .Cache(c=>c
       .UseQueryCache()
         .ProviderClass<HashtableCacheProvider>())
       .ShowSql())
     .Mappings(m => ................);
```

Query throws error (`WITH` clause was added in mssql2008):

> The query should start with 'SELECT' or 'SELECT DISTINCT'
>
> [NotSupportedException: The query should start with 'SELECT' or 'SELECT DISTINCT']
>      NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect.GetAfterSelectInsertPoint(SqlString sql) +179
>      NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect.GetLimitString(SqlString querySqlString, Int32 offset, Int32 limit) +119
>      NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect.GetLimitString(SqlString querySqlString, Int32 offset, Int32 last) +127
>      NHibernate.Loader.Loader.PrepareQueryCommand(QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean scroll, ISessionImplementor session) +725
>      NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) +352
>      NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) +114
>      NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +205

---

Any ideas what exactly confuses nhibernate and how to fix it?

---

Guilty NHibernate code (in NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql200Dialect.cs):

```
private static int GetAfterSelectInsertPoint(SqlString sql)
{
  if (sql.StartsWithCaseInsensitive("select distinct"))
  {
    return 15;
  }
  else if (sql.StartsWithCaseInsensitive("select"))
  {
    return 6;
  }
  throw new NotSupportedException
    ("The query should start with 'SELECT' or 'SELECT DISTINCT'");
  }
}
```

Looks that `.SetMaxResults(123)` causes this. Fortunately, i can unbound that query.

Hopefully that will fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue (removing `SetMaxResults` also helped but I needed paging) and found out that the following NHibernate configuration property was causing this bug:

```
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

It's certainly a bug, because the `GetAfterSelectInsertPoint` method doesn't take into account that SQL comments may be prepended to the SQL query.

Just set the `use_sql_comments` property to `false` and the problem disappears.

Comment: Cannot believe it happened again!

Answer (score 4):

I repaired the bug using Alkampfer's solution, but I created my own SQL dialect rather than patching the NHibernate source directly:

```
public class Sql2008DialectWithBugFixes : MsSql2008Dialect
{
    public override SqlString GetLimitString(SqlString querySqlString, int offset, int last)
    {
        if (offset == 0)
        {
            return querySqlString.Insert(GetAfterSelectInsertPoint(querySqlString), " top " + last);
        }

        return base.GetLimitString(querySqlString, offset, last);
    }

    private static int GetAfterSelectInsertPoint(SqlString sql)
    {
        Int32 selectPosition;

        if ((selectPosition = sql.IndexOfCaseInsensitive("select distinct")) >= 0)
        {
            return selectPosition + 15; // "select distinct".Length;

        }
        if ((selectPosition = sql.IndexOfCaseInsensitive("select")) >= 0)
        {
            return selectPosition + 6; // "select".Length;
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException("The query should start with 'SELECT' or 'SELECT DISTINCT'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem using a similar query which has a WITH clause.

Unfortunately, my query populates a grid, with paging, so I have to keep SetMaxResults.

My solution was to rewrite using a Derived Table:

```
var sql = @"with Foo(col1,col2,col3)
              as (select x1, x2, x3 from x join y blabla)
            Select col1, col2, col3 from Foo
            join B on B.col1 = Foo.col1";
```

becomes

```
var sql = @"Select col1, col2, col3 from 
           (select x1 as col1, x2 as col2, x3 as col3 
            from x join y blabla) as Foo
           join B on B.col1 = Foo.col1";
```

Just to allow NHibernate to insert the " TOP x " string after the "select" string (6 characters from the begining)... No comment :(

T

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is some strange bug in the routine used to find the place in the query to insert the TOP clause (GetAfterSelectInsertPoint ) as told by Sandor. You can fix it directly in nh source (I actually patched 2.1 version I'm using in a project, you can [find details here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/07/28/a-strange-bug-in-nhibernate-2-1/)). So if you absolutely needs to enable comments with use_sql_comments you can :)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem when upgrading from 1.2 to 3.2 (I know, BIG jump eh?).

The issue in my case was that there is a leading space in front of the select statement in the hql, e.g. String hql = " select "...

With SQL2005 Dialect, this crashes with a "System.NotSupportedException: The query should start with 'SELECT'..." message.

The solution is to

1. create a unit test that fails, a good Test Driven Developer
   should :)
2. remove the leading space from the " select..." statement
3. build and run the unit test

Answer (score 0):

Just as i predicted - unbounding select is acceptable workaround.

Deleted `SetMaxResults` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue when upgrading to NHibernate version 3.3, but for a different reason...whitespace.  We had a lot of sql strings that looked like this:

```
var sql = @"
select col1 from MyTable";
```

or:

```
var sql = @" select col1 from My Table";
```

These resulted in the "The query should start with 'SELECT' or 'SELECT DISTINCT'" errors because NHibernate doesn't trim the string before validating it.

We created a new dialect that trims the string first to get around this:

```
public class Sql2008DialectCustom : MsSql2008Dialect
{
  public override SqlString GetLimitString(SqlString queryString, SqlString offset, SqlString limit)
  {
    var trimmedQueryString = queryString.Trim();
    return base.GetLimitString(trimmedQueryString, offset, limit);
  }
}
```