# ActiveRecord: How do I add NOLOCK?

Tags: activerecord

I need to add "WITH NOLOCK" when using ActiveRecord? I know there is a way to do it nHibernate, but couldn't figure this out in ActiveRecord.

Thank you for your help.
Regards,

Comment: Here is my solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302746/how-do-add-nolock-with-nhibernate/39518098#39518098

Answer (score 2):

Not to revive an old post. But there is an option to lock per query rather than setting it in the model.

For Example:

```
Account.where("name = 'shugo'").lock(true).first
```

Check out this link for more info.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but here is the answer:

```
criteria.SetLockMode(NHibernate.LockMode.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using  `:lock => 'WITH (NOLOCK)'` in query works with current versions of activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (2.3.24 and 3.2.10 at the time of writing).

If you want it to be added to all queries for particular model, just put

```
default_scope :lock => 'WITH (NOLOCK)'
```

in your model.

Comment: this will lock the row.  Big fail

Comment: WITH(ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK) to be percise

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your activerecord model

```
default_scope joins('WITH (NOLOCK)')
```

Do **NOT** do :lock => 'with (NOLOCK)' it will lock each row with "WITH(ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK)"

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think it will lock each row with additional locks ? Because I've used this hack without any problems in a big legacy project. As far as I see it, :lock => 'with(NOLOCK)' just adds WITH(NOLOCK) clause to the query, here is corresponding spec from sqlserver adapter - https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/blob/e95d1f4a4a62932a37d0eefbb3ff4e8a26dfb03b/test/cases/pessimistic_locking_test_sqlserver.rb#L53 . Am I missing something ?

Comment: not sure, all i know is when i used that code I had that happen to me "WITH(ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK)"

Comment: It appears that currently (v1.3.7 and earlier), when you use :lock => 'WITH (NOLOCK)', activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter will use "WITH(ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK)", whereas activerecord-sqlserver-adapter will do the right thing.  joins('WITH (NOLOCK)') sometimes generates invalid sql on both when you try and use associations.

Answer (score 0):

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
     class SQLServerAdapter  < AbstractAdapter

         alias :old_raw_select :raw_select

         def raw_select(sql, name = nil)
            sql.gsub! %r{FROM\s\[(\w+)\]\s}im, "FROM [\\1] with (nolock)"
            old_raw_select(sql,name)
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
default_scope {
    lock('WITH (NOLOCK)')
}
```