# Nhibernate lockmode issue

Tags: nhibernate

I am using Nhibernate 2.12 and am having an issue with LockMode. I am trying to add NoLock to the sql statement on an alias. When I do this using a crieria that doesn't provide a projectionlist it works fine. But when I add a projection list it gives me a nasty 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error on the NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.ApplyLocks(SqlString sqlSelectString, IDictionary`2 lockModes, Dialect dialect) part of nhibernate.

Am I missing something?

Phil

Comment: Here is my solution by using SQL Interceptor.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302746/how-do-add-nolock-with-nhibernate/39518098#39518098

Answer (score 0):

I think projections is not support locking, so try to not use locking when using projections.