# Modify SQL in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I need to know how to modify a sql, to add to every select a sql code.
My problem is, I need to add this sql code after a "FROM table" + " sql_code", even if there is something after "like a GROUP BY".

I know that I need to use the OnPrepareStatement, I just don't know how to edit the SqlString to do so !

One thing that I've tried:

```
public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
       if (sql.Parts.Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault().Trim().ToLower() != "select")
        {
            return sql;
        }
        StringBuilder novaString = new StringBuilder(sql.ToString());
        String corte = sql.SubstringStartingWithLast("where").ToString();
        if (corte != "")
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(corte);
            sb.Insert(0, "with(nolock) ");
            novaString.Replace(corte, sb.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            novaString.Append(" with(nolock)");
        }
        return new SqlString(novaString.ToString());
    }
```

Thanks !

Comment: I didn't know what that means. I will, sorry !

Comment: He means you need to mark one of the answers in each your previous questions as "accepted", that is if there are answers and they helped.

Comment: yes, I got that part ! Do you have any idea of my issue ? Thanks guys !

Comment: Show us some code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Rippo So, I tried that code, but the second time it runs (when there is a strange sql code with _0_0) it returns this error: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/exceptionh.png/

Comment: Have you read this S.O. answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302746/how-do-add-nolock-with-nhibernate

Comment: @Rippo My problem is, I need the with(nolock) to be shown on the sql dump ! I just need to fix something in that code ! Thanks !

Comment: @Rippo I have re edited my code, I'd like to know how to fix the error of the img http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/exceptionh.png/ ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party but here is how I optomize some of our queries.  The below takes a given sql statement and appends a little bit to the end:

```
public class OptionInterceptor: EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        var parameters = sql.GetParameters();
        var paramCount = parameters.Count();

        if (paramCount > 0)
            return sql;

        string optionString = " OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (";

        for (var i = 0; i < paramCount; i++)
        {
            var comma = i > 0 ? "," : string.Empty;
            optionString = optionString + comma + "@p" + i + " UNKNOWN";
        }

        optionString = optionString + "))";

        var builder = new SqlStringBuilder(sql);

        builder.Add(optionString);

        return builder.ToSqlString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late, but still. I had to add a hint into generated sql:

```
private class SqlLogger : EmptyInterceptor
{
    private const string Select = "SELECT";
    private const int SelectLen = 6;
    private const string Hint = " /*+ dynamic_sampling(0) */";
    private const char Param = '?';

    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        var s = sql.ToString().ToUpper();
        var start = s.IndexOf(Select, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (start != -1)
            s = s.Insert(SelectLen, Hint);

        var builder = new SqlStringBuilder();
        var parts = s.Split(Param);
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            builder.Add(parts[i]);
            builder.AddParameter();
        }
        builder.Add(parts.Last());
        sql = builder.ToSqlString();

        return sql;
    }
}
```