# Understanding effects of with (updlock, rowlock) on a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate to query data from a reporting database and would like to optimize READ performance. "Dirty reads" are not a concern at all. NHibernate provides Lock Modes. If I use the LockMode.UpgradeNoWait mode I can see that in the generated SQL a 'with (updlock, rowlock)' appears. I've been reading up on this, but my SQL is unfortunately not sophisticated  enough to really understand the ramifications. I believe what I really want is a 'with (nolock)' statement to appear, but NHibernate does not see to provide any way of doing that.

My question then is this: Let's say my table is being written to in other transactions.  Will the 'with (updlock, rowlock)' hint in a query against this table cause it to return any faster? Can it hurt performance? The query is a very simple select against a single table. No joins. There is a non-clustered index on the table that covers the query.

Answer (score 4):

The `updlock` will place **update locks** on every row being touched (selected) - so this means until the end of the transaction (explicit or implicit), the row(s) touched by the `SELECT` will have an update lock on them which allows for other transactions to read, but not update or delete the row.

The `rowlock` just indicates that you want **row-level locks** instead of page or table locks.

That lock makes sense if you need to select first, then update a row within the same explicit transaction.

It doesn't make it run any faster, and can cause other transactions to be blocked

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was mistaken about the use of Lock modes in NHibernate. They do not have anything to do with adding the nolock hint to a query. [This is the way to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302746/how-do-add-nolock-with-nhibernate%20%22This%20is%20the%20way%22%20to%20do%20it.)